# Can I turn cloud into house?

Tags: internal-consistency, architecture, weather

What kind of cloud is suitable for carrying people and what 21st century technology can enable people to reside on the cloud? As long as our weight is supported only by the cloud itself anything goes.

Comment: You understand that clouds are basically steam right?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Walking on clouds](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/15051/6986)

Answer (score 5):

No sort of cloud is suitable for carrying people, or houses.

Clouds are basically steam.
We are talking tiny particle of water suspended in air 
(Not technically a gas).
Clouds close to the ground are Fog.
If you walk up a mountain, and notice it is foggy all the time, that is because you are walking through clouds.

They are incapable of supporting weight.

Now the next question is are their enough reliable wind current to lift anything house sized, and keep it in the air for a while.
After all [this is how raining frogs works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rain_of_animals).
I've got to say no. There is just no way. Too heavy, and even if it could be lifted it would be so thrown around, and so likely to fall, it would not be "residing on the cloud" but riding it.

Nope.
Can not do.
You could fake it though, with a lighter than air craft hidden inside clouds.

Comment: You can do it if you wrap the cloud in fabric and [heat it a bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_air_balloon) or [change the air composition inside somewhat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lighter_than_air). For some rather loose definition of *cloud*.

Comment: I was thinking that, but that works just as well, if not better with air that does not contain water vapour.