End effect of precognition in a physical fight
For context, I am writing a magic system that allows certain users to have short-term (a few seconds) precognition exclusively of their opponent. This means that they know what their opponent will do at any given moment, as they can see it. The problem is when two people with the same precognitive ability fight. Would a fight between two equals with precognitive ability converge to a perfect fight or diverge into a rapidly changing mess?
For context, all weapons are handheld blade weapons, as many opponents would have enough time to easily dodge projectiles like arrows.
My thoughts for the first option:

In the first scenario, the two fighters know what their opponent will do and so they plan to do something better. This concept repeats itself until both opponents are equally matched and neither can defeat the other. Both individuals have perfect counters to the other's move. In this case, the one with the most endurance would probably win.
I think of chess engines, who also predict each other's moves. In chess games between the top engines where they start from a balanced position, they both hold each other off at a draw to infinity.

My thoughts for the second option:

In the second scenario, the two fighters change plans after seeing their opponents next action, causing a chain reaction where both see the opponents constantly changing plans of action. This would often make the fights deciding factor reaction time.

For two equal opponents, making daring moves that are not the best move would result in a loss, so I don't think that would ever be done. The answer might be affected by how different their plans are at the start, but there is no need for that level of detail for now.

Chess engines and "precognition" have nothing in common. Well, they shouldn't. Precog, as usually defined, is seeing into the future. One linear path. Or at least a fuzzy idea of one path. A chess engine will calculate all possible future moves. Well, likely, there would be heuristics to narrow down the possibilities (even at low depth, there is bound to be thousands of options) but still choose between many. Opponent makes a move A, the engine knows to answer with X. But if opponent does move B, then the answer would be Y. Regular humans do this all the time. Precog implies one path.

At any rate what would happen depends on what you want. There is nothing else to base it on. Two precog fighting might mean to "cancelling out" their powers. Or it could be that they both have perfect knowledge that they get to use, therefore being unable to do anything but counter one another. Or both might just fall down with the worst headache in their lives due to the explosion of possible futures in their minds. Or anything else. You, as the author, should define it. There is no One True answer to what should happen. Because we do not have authoritative explanation. It's made up. By you

This sounds really similar to a particular power in Brandon Sanderson's Mistborn series, which allowed short term precognition. If I remember correctly, he solved this problem by making the precogs counter each other. Because your move is based off of the other person's, and theirs off yours, if both people use this power the future becomes fuzzed out because there's just a bunch of uncertain causality going on. This is kind of an unsatisfying answer, though... Sanderson makes this interesting by making the power a limited resource, so it's not constantly in use. I'd suggest you do the same.

Dune series considers this concern  Many small decisions cloud the predictions. But that is how Dune handles it.

"all weapons are handheld blade weapons, as many opponents would have enough time to easily dodge projectiles" - if they can easily dodge projectiles, then they could even more easily dodge the much slower handheld weapons.

Have you read Brandon Sanderson's Mistborn serie? In it, mistborns (the pinnacle of allomancers) can activate a mythical (and very expensive) metal to see the future. There are specifically discussions about what happens when two mistborns do so, and fights between such. I'd recommend reading and see if this appeals to you.

This is not opinion-based.  As a martial artist, I believe that this is capable of a definitive answer.

Possible duplicate: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/10939/75

How often does the precognition update? If your opponent is coming at you with attack A, but you foresee it and move into stance to defend that attack, your opponent may see you react and decide to attack differently. In that case, you should begin to see a different future, but now that you know they're going for a different attack, you take a different stance, which they see and... etc etc etc. I've never really found a way to make foresight fully logically consistent

Another question is: is foresight literally vision of the future, or just somehow knowing what is going to happen? If it's the former, is the foresight's origin your current eye location, or your future eye location? Either way you'll be completely susceptible to attack from behind, unless in the future you're going to look behind you, which lets you see behind you, but if you can see behind yourself already you no longer need to turn around in the future, so you don't, but that means you don't get future sight of you turning around, but that means...

@VLAZ I'd challenge that. Chess is a game of perfect information as all the opponent can do is right there on the table. What you can do is, with perfect knowledge, choose a move such that even an opponent with perfect knowledge will eventually be unable to defend. Surely "if I do this, the best move he can counter with is that" counts as precognition? Even with precognition, the opponent will chose what to do based on what you do first and vice versa.

@JollyJoker serious chess players study existing strategies. These strategies cover moves and their counter moves. Amateur chess players look at the board and try to enumerate all possible moves and prepare to what might come as a response. But this is exceptionally hard, as you need to consider way too many possibilities and the breadth of options few steps ahead is staggering. Chess masters are better at this but they also know not to consider every single possible move. Perhaps if you move the rook, you check the other player so their possible moves is vastly lower. And chess

strategies further refine that because they give you a board state to strive to. This board state gives you more options, while suppressing the opponent's. From such a board state you can then push the game further in your advantage by eliminating the opponent's figures.  Chess engines work similar by using heuristics to choose which board state to go towards. Consider all possible board states as a graph, linked by moves. Chess engines traverse that graph. There is no one path.

In a way chess does allow for "perfect knowledge". In theory, you could picture all possible board positions. However, the human mind does not. Consider tic-tac-toe. That's a solved game. I solved it myself with a pen and paper when I was about 10. Just figured all possible moves. The fact that 1. we still play chess competitively thousands of years later, suggests that's not the case for chess. 2. If it were really solved, we wouldn't even need to have chess masters play against each other. They'd draw every single time. Well, they don't.

Just wanted to comment on this part: "precognition exclusively of their opponent". I believe that this would ALSO let them know when someone else attacks them - because if my precognition shows my opponent suddenly relaxing their combat stance, someone else must've taken future-me out. If he nods at someone behind future-me, current-me should probably do something about the guy who is about to stab me in the back.

"Now, now, perfectly symmetrical violence never solved anything!" -Hubert Farnsworth

Can you explain your ideas about the differences between '… a perfect fight…' and ' 'a rapidly changing mess?'
Otherwise, what could any Answer depend on but the SE Member's opinions about those differences?
If in all things, including precognition, your warriors are equally balanced, then how could their fight turn on anything but luck?

A straight answer
I'll try to answer this straight, without getting bogged down in side issues that subvert the question, like the difficulty of following the precognition, failures of attention, different thinking speeds, etc.
So, let's assume the precognition is perfect, and followed perfectly and equally well by both. What does this mean? You mentioned chess engines, so let's suppose both combatants have a version of "perfect play" like an ideal chess engine could have.
For this analysis, assume the fight consists of a series of turns - each lasting something like 10 milliseconds - and in each turn each combatant may choose an action - each action being to activate certain muscles. At the end of the fight there is an outcome; each combatant takes a certain amount of injury, perhaps lethal perhaps not. The combatants each have a preference across all possible outcomes; each combatant ranks each outcome from best to worst.
For the precognitive combatants to have "perfect play" can be defined as them choosing the maximin move at each turn. This means they always choose the move that guarantees them the best outcome they can be sure to achieve from the current position, in the worst case of what their opponent might do to thwart them.
Given these premises, the outcome depends on what the weapons are. You said we are talking melee bladed weapons. Any armor? Suppose no armor.
MAD
Suppose the weapon is a knife. Knife fights in real life are often a matter of mutually assured destruction (MAD); either combatant, if they have enough disregard for their own life, could rush in and inflict a serious, perhaps lethal wound on their opponent. It takes time for the reckless aggressor to die from any wound, and in that time they can stab several times.
This is true also for longer weapons. In real-world competitive fencing, fights are determined by who strikes the first blow. But the opponent's strike often comes mere milliseconds after that. If they didn't care about who was first and just charged, they would both hit.
This may not hold up in a precognitive combat (see "mirroring" below). But if it does, then there will never be a one-sided victory where one combatant gets away unscathed and the other is dead. The possible outcomes in a melee MAD scenario are one combatant wins (by virtue of being stronger/faster/taller) but is grievously injured himself; both combatants kill each other; or, knowing that these are the outcomes and neither wanting them, both combatants decline to engage.
There won't be any "testing of defenses." Both combatants know from the start what's going to happen, just like a perfect chess engine knows immediately whether any given position is win/loss/draw with perfect play. All that remains is just to do it.
Large physical disparities
If one combatant has a substantial physical advantage over the other, then that combatant is not going to lose, and probably going to win. They can overpower their opponent, outmaneuver them, or outreach them. Grabbing the opponent's wrist to turn the melee into a wrestling match could be a winning strategy.
Mirroring
A precognitive knife fight is different from a normal one, because it's harder to get past the defender's guard, assuming the defender has something to block with such as a bundled rag or piece of wood. The attacker can't feint one way, then go the other way to get around the defender's guard, because the defender will never fall for a feint. If the defender isn't too different in reach or speed from the attacker, the defender can simply mirror the attacker's motions perfectly, so the defender's blocking hand will always be there to meet the attacker's weapon.
So it's plausible that a precognitive knife fight between physically fairly even combatants who have something to block with, would be a draw, with neither able to inflict an injury - or last until the combatants are exhausted and the one who is physically less exhausted wins.
Of course, if neither of the combatants would gain a decisive victory from such a battle of exhaustion, then it won't even start; they'll just agree not to fight at the beginning.
Compounding small advantages
In chess, when a position is close to even, strong chess engines will spend a long time jockeying for position - trying to compound small positional advantages that might eventually result in a win. (Although: when the position is close to even, it usually just is even, and the outcome is a draw regardless of this jockeying.)
What would this look like in a knife fight? One of the combatants might be a little taller, with longer reach, or they might be a little faster. So they might try to get around their opponent, to make the position asymmetrical. That's the only way they're going to get around the opponent's mirroring defense.
My intuition, picturing this, is that this is usually not going to work. The opponent just needs to take an occasional step back to nullify any such positional jockeying.
This does mean that the combatant with a physical advantage can make his opponent take steps back, and that might be used to corner him, if the terrain is advantageous. On the other hand, if the terrain is open enough, the defender can just retreat in a circle so nothing changes.
Note that making the defender trip over something as he retreats backwards is impossible; they're a perfect precog, so they could fight with their eyes closed and it would make no difference.
Armor
The precog enemy's aim for any gaps in the armor would be perfect. So, in one sense armor may not be as effective in a precog combat as it would be in a normal combat. If you're wearing full plate with a 1 cm eye slit in the helmet, the enemy can just casually stab his sword right into that slit without any hesitation or delay.
A precog combatant doesn't actually need an eye slit, eyes being superfluous compared to his precognitive sense, but the same holds for other small gaps in the armor.
What armor does do is limit the points the enemy can target; only the eye slit, and not the side of the head, for example. This means that the defender only needs to deflect the incoming attack slightly to make it miss; he doesn't have to stop it entirely.
This doesn't mean the defender will spend much time actually deflecting incoming attacks, though. The attacker won't bother making any attack the defender can block.
So, armor makes precog combat even more likely to end in a draw.
Longer weapons
Obviously, a longer weapon is an advantage against a shorter one. If you have a sword and the enemy has a knife, and you're both precogs, you almost certainly win. The enemy can't really mirror your motions because you can whip the point of the sword around faster than he can move his blocking hand, because of the lever arm of the sword.
If both precogs have longer weapons, the battle might be less likely to shed any blood, because parries are easier. A precog knife fight is drawish because both combatants can injure each other, whereas a precog rapier fight is drawish because neither combatant can score a hit.
The precogs aren't likely to waste much time clashing swords and parrying, though. They know their strikes would be parried, so they have little to gain from making them, unless they have more stamina and are trying to exhaust their opponent.
Ranged weapons
You discounted ranged weapons, but they would actually be quite powerful and difficult to dodge. Suppose your precog opponent is 20 ft away shooting an arrow at a respectable 200 fps. You have 0.1 seconds to dodge. If they aimed for your chest, it is not possible to move your chest out of the way in 0.1 seconds. (And remember, the opponent is precog, so unlike with a non-precog opponent, it is not possible to anticipate ahead of time where their aiming point will be and get out of the way before they shoot. They can keep their aiming point dead center on your chest however you move and can't be faked out, so you really do have only 0.1 seconds to react.)
You might try to deflect the arrow instead of dodging it - for example, using your dagger. But the problem there is that the bow-wielding enemy can change his aiming point faster than you can move your hand. He only needs to make a tiny motion to switch his aim from your thigh to your neck, while you have to move your hand a couple feet. So the enemy just needs to flip his aiming point a couple times until your dagger isn't in the way, then shoot.
If you're in full plate armor, however, a tiny motion lasting 0.1 seconds could make his arrow miss your eye slit. Though of course, he's not going to actually shoot in that case; he'll save his shot until he precognitively knows it will hit. If you're armored enough that none of his shots will ever hit, he knows immediately and will just either retreat or switch weapons without bothering to shoot.

It seems like deflecting an incoming missile should still work for a precog combatant.  They don't need to move faster than the shooter changes aim, for if their precognition is enough to be any combat advantage at all then they know before the shot where the missile is going to come.

@JohnBollinger The thing is the attacker is a precog too. Say the attacker is aiming at the defender's throat and the defender wants to block it with a dagger. Where is the defender's blocking hand? If the defender's hand is not near his throat, then the attacker can simply release the arrow, and the defender physically can't get his hand in position to block quickly enough. If the defender's hand is near his throat, then the attacker simply whips the aim down to the defender's thigh and shoots, and again the defender physically cannot move his hand fast enough to intercept.

@JohnBollinger It's just like in chess. Two ideal, perfect chess players don't know which move the other is going to make, only which moves they could make. It's like if a chess player has two ways to checkmate his opponent's king, and the opponent can prevent either of them but not both - so the outcome of the game is checkmate. The attacker could shoot the arrow at the defender's neck, or at his thigh, and the defender can't have his hand in ready position to block them both.

If it helps, imagine you are a non-precog having a swordfight with a precog who is moving in 10x slow motion. Even though you aren't a precog yourself, you can still beat him by just stabbing him where his limbs physically can't block you in time.

That argument -- which is a plausible way to look at it, to be sure -- comes down to precogs canceling out each other's ability.  You don't need precognition to know what the opponent could do, or how you could counter it, etc..  If you don't know what they will do then you are not experiencing precognition.  And indeed, that seems a natural outgrowth of starting with (non-precognitive) chess engines as the model.  That's fine, but it might be nice to be clearer about that up front.

@JohnBollinger As the slow-motion swordfight example shows, it doesn't even necessarily take another precog to get around a precog's guard. Heck, a dumb robot could do it; you program the robot to shoot the precog's neck or thigh, depending on where the precog's blocking hand currently is. If the robot is fast enough at shifting the aim point, the precog can't compensate. In a sense the precog does "know" where the projectile will hit, but only after the precog decides on his own course of action. His own course of action determines the future, and in both possible futures he gets hit.

That seems to be an argument that precognition, in the sense of knowing the future in advance, is not possible in situations where events are responsive to the supposed-precog's precognition-informed actions.  I think I buy it. And it doesn't necessarily have to be all or nothing, of course.  What an interesting idea for the OP to explore!

one note on the ranged weapons: a quick googling told me that a recurve-bow fired arrow travels 300 feet per second. So if we're assuming .1 seconds of precognition, the one with the bow cannot precognize the target's dodging moves if he's further than 30 feet away - because at the end of a precognition time window starting when he releases, the arrow is still in flight so the target still has time to perform (not foreseen) dodging. So precogs with ranged weapons would want to fire them at really close range, and precogs facing ranged weapons would want to either get away, or rush into melee.

maybe that's where the dungeons and dragons rule that certain abilities only work with ranged weapons if you're within 30 ft of the target comes from?^^

This is a great opportunity because it reflects a basic need of worldbuilding
And what is that need? You need to choose what rule you want.
As you can imagine, there is no science, no real-world example, nothing that we can draw from that will give you an objective and definitive answer. Insofar as we know, precognition doesn't exist. That puts you square in the middle of "the result will be what you want it to be."
I know that's not what you wanted to hear, but it's actually a good place to be! Here there be dragons worldbuilding! And you get to decide what the rules of your imaginary world are and how those rules work.
However, we can give you some pointers
Let's ask ourselves what about real life might contribute to this issue?

People "think" at different speeds. This is actually a lot more complicated than it sounds. Some people are naturally more observant than others. Some people can reach a conclusion faster than others. Some people have better control during a fight (see adrenaline and the fight/flight reflex) than others. Some people are better trained than others. What all this means is that you will believably never have a situation where the two opponents are perfectly matched. When all the pros and cons are analyzed, one will always have an advantage over the other. Unfortunately, this is more storybuilding than it is worldbuilding.

Then there's bad luck. Or good luck! It depends on whether or not you're the winner. I've watched tennis matches played by opponents so well balanced that it wasn't someone's game to win... it was someone's game to lose. That's a very real thing. It reflects the reality that in some cases, it's not the first to outsmart their opponent who wins, but the first who makes a mistake who loses. And that ignores the simple truth that someti... SQUIRREL! Yup, sometimes you just have the bad luck of the exact type of pretty girl walking by at exactly the wrong time to get that specific "you're sleepin' on the couch tonight, mister" look from your wife. Crap happens.

How much of an advantage precognition is depends heavily on the rules of its operation. Is the practitioner actually seeing something in their mind? That's a huge distraction. Is it intuitive, meaning it's a better form of what a good fighter can do anyway through training ("guessing" or predicting what will happen next)? This is an important question because how you define precognition determines whether two gods are fighting or two people struggling to use a tool. Think of it this way... in a world where pretty much every soldier has an M1 carbine the rare soldier lugging around an M50 machine gun has a distinct advantage... kinda... because that machine gun has negatives that are very useful to a story (it's heavy, it has greater recoil, it takes time to set up, if simply held and fired it gets HOT...). BTW, godlike characters are boring. You want weaknesses or your readers won't relate well to the story.


In other words, you're asking us the wrong question
Yup, there is no right answer to your question and that's an important learning experience for asking future questions. Note from the Help Center that giving us your answers and expecting more (telling us what you've already considered) is prohibited unless you're explaining why they're not valuable answers, in which case they become conditions. Note also that questions are expected to identify a problem to be solved. I know you feel that's what you identified, but I hope I've helped you understand that you've asked us to voice opinions with no hope of evidence that one opinion is better than another (also prohibited...). It's worth taking the time to read the fist two pages in the Help Center (it's useful to read them all, but those are the most important).
For future reference, our sweet spot is answering questions like, "I want X in my world, how do I rationalize it?" and "I want X in my world but need help working out the rules, my specific problem today is X...." In other words, you've already made your choice about what you want in your world and need help smoothing out the rules. We're great at that. Helping you decide which way to go? You'd be surprised how hard that is — if it can be done at all.
Cheers and happy worldbuilding!

So would a better question be "How (given story context) could I balance a precognitive duel that converges" ?

@ShieldCat Nope. By definition the outcome of a specific fight is storybuilding and questions about how to tell your story are prohibited in the [help/on-topic]. Worldbuilding is defining the rules of precognition. Kinda worldbuilding is helping you develop the rules of training someone who is precognate. How precognition is used would always be storybuilding. Note that, as I pointed out, there will never be a time when skills converge to equality, so you're probably worrying for no reason.

Another rule to consider: does their precognition recursively take into account the other person's precognition, or does it only update after they react to their precognition?  If the latter, then the future you see is going to keep shifting, which might manifest as form of "future-sickness", akin to vertigo.  Suddenly, the person who is only looking half a second into the future has an advantage over the person looking a full second into the future, because their vision is "shifting" less.

@Chronocidal That's a good point and might be a pretty good answer to the OP's original question. I.E., one way to resolve his/her concern is to decide the nature of how two precognates react to each other. It's a great observation and idea!

@JBH Thanks for the help with understanding how to properly write questions that are appropriate for this site. Sorry about that. In the end, I did find many of the answers here to be helpful in my design of the precognitive system, as they answered the question that I was trying to ask, not the one that I did ask. Also, my suggested replacement title was not talking about specific fight, but under the assumption of the converging precognition theory, how could I escape constant perfect draws. Thanks again! :)

In Tad Williams' 'Memory, Sorrow, and Thorn' series the first fights he described between Sithi and Norns (his 'elves') showed them with most duels being over with a single strike.   Each would study their opponent until they saw an opening and then they would strike.
I could see two precog duelists doing the same.   They watch their opponent, waiting for a moment's lack of attention or balance.  And then they strike.
However, if a skilled, non-precog, duelist fought a less skilled, precog, duelist, the precog's ability may just allow him to see the death stroke slightly before he actually receives it.
Knowing that someone is going to punch you in the face doesn't necessarily mean you can stop them from punching you in the face.

I especially appreciate this answer for focusing on the limitations of precognition. We've all been in a game or sport where we could finally see what was coming, but too late to do anything about it.

All the answers here forget one thing: Fatigue.
As a martial artist (red belt in Shotokan Karate and Hapkido), I have the experience to know that if you aren't hit and disabled by an attack that you failed to anticipate, fatigue is going to get you.
If both sides are precognitive, there aren't going to be any mistakes.  The fight is going to be pure exercise, with each combatant trying to score and prevent their opponent from scoring... and with precognition, neither side is going to score straight away.
However, as these combatants are fighting, they're going to be expending energy, running down their physical reserves... and sooner or later, someone's reserves are going to run out.
As a student of the marial arts, we did an exercise where one person would fight against a line of other people, ten seconds for each opponent until they had gone through the whole line, then the next person would take over fighting the line and the first person would go to the back of the line.  With a long enough line, you're fighting for as much as several minutes.
During that time, if you're not the fittest person in the dojo, you're getting tired... and sooner or later, you're going to run into a situation where you're too fatigued to be able to counter the attacks coming at you, even though you can see how to counter them.  At that point, precognition is not going to help you.
He who gets fatigued first, loses.

Keep in mind that both combatants know from the start who is going to get exhausted first, so likely it won't get to that point. The combatant with less stamina will either flee if possible before the combat starts, or will prepare to fight in a way that trades injury for injury even though losing, which could make the putative winner back off before the fight starts instead of accepting a win at the cost of injury.

@causative To quote the OP: For context, I am writing a magic system that allows certain users to have short-term (a few seconds) precognition exclusively of their opponent.  It takes more than a few seconds to get fatigued.

Jedi
Canonically, all Jedi are precognitive. That's how they can deflect blaster bolts which otherwise go too fast for humans to track. What happens when they fight?
Generally the answer is "boss fight"! But more than that, the winner is generally determined by how skilled they are at fighting. Knowing the future is one thing, but being able to physically move your blade in time, or position yourself on terrain so that you have the advantage, those are skills which give you the edge.
Sherlock
In the BBC series Sherlock,
Sherlock Holmes isn't truly precognitive. Rather, he has a superhuman ability to extrapolate. In the episode The Reichenbach Fall, he faces an opponent who is similarly able, and the pair both mentally track a fight which ends with Holmes's defeat. They both know the outcome. Holmes then takes an alternative option of going over the Falls together, faster than the other man can react.
A general case for precognition here would be that your precognitive skills can only cover what you focus on. They don't cover left field attacks (or defences) which you don't know to think about.

There is also an Asian movie where two kung-fu fighters play the fight in their head before engaging (this happens in black and white). This is under rain and with an older blind player of [a guitar-like music instrument]. They then actually fight once the player breaks one of his strings. I cannot find the title of the movie.

@WoJ Hero, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hero_(2002_film)

@sidbushes thanks! I googled all kinds of words combinations from my description above but this one did not come up (or if it did, it was not this scene so I did not recognize it)

This is an expansion of @vlaz excellent comments
Knowing all possible moves vs knowing the exact move are not the same.
Let us use a bounded system - such as noughts and crosses (or Tick-Tack-toe for my American readers) to demonstrate this:
I know my opponent will make a move and there is a small and ever decreasing number of places - such that any competent opponents will end-up in a stalemate (Gotta include the classic scene from War Games here)
So - how do you win a game? Well there are two elements required for a victory:
1: Your opponent makes a mistake
2: You force your opponent into a situation where they can only stop 1 of 2 paths to victory.
e.g. see this GIF: As an example
Regardless of what the opponent chooses to do, there they cannot block both vectors of attack - so they loose.
This is the first option - it isn't true precognition, it is knowing the all the possible moves and rank-ordering them by probability - the two fighters attempt to force each other into a position whereby the other cannot counter all the possible attacks and so leaves themselves open.
Option 2 - Long Term planning, limits of human agility and cool-downs
You mentioned that Pre-Cog only allows for a few seconds of vision into the future. So let us assume our protagonist knows this - and so prepares the fight with a series of long-term (e.g. past the point of Precog vision) items to give them the victory.
If my opponent can see 2 seconds into the future, but they do not know that 4 seconds away (at a run) I have hidden a rifle - by the time they are within precog vision of knowing I have a gun, they have at most 2 seconds to find cover or attempt to counter it - 2 seconds is not a lot of time to get out of line-of-sight or find hard cover. I am using a Rifle just for illustrative purposes - luring them into a trap where they will not be able to escape the perimeter of the trap in the time that precog allows will still work.
In addition - is your Precog ability always on - or is it something that you have to consciously summon - if it is the latter, then you could have some form of cool-down (e.g. it takes a certain amount of effort to cast it and you need to recover a bit before casting it again) - in which case, a Precog vs Precog fight would revolve around who can cast it in the most tactically advantageous moment.
Finally - and I kinda touched on this above - there are limits to human agility and speed. Those that have ever been in a Car Crash will know that there is a moment when you can see what is about to happen, yet you have no ability to significantly change the outcome - all the precog in the world is not going to help you if an Avalanche is thundering towards you or a massive explosion goes off - no matter what you do, you cannot get out of the danger area fast enough with only a few seconds.
Manipulating this fact is how two precog fighters with always on precog would attempt to battle - getting them into a position where 2 seconds is not enough to escape their fate.

precognition problems
First of all, knowing what someone else will do does not equal a perfect reaction. Think of it like this. I have a ball launching machine. You can catch a ball in midair by clapping your hands together at the right time. I give you the exact time, speed and everything else you need. Can you always catch the ball? The answer is no, you cannot. Precognition only means you know what is going to happen, giving you time to plan. Plans do not necessarily pan out. They can be wrong, or wrongly implemented, or simply physically impossible to enact.
Take the 'no projectiles' example. However much precognition you have, at a certain time the arrow goes too fast from a too short range to deflect or evade them. There simply isn't enough physical time, unless you weren’t there in the first place. As someone is aiming at you right then and there you've already lost.
But let's say this is magically solved by the precognition spell. What then?
Time to be alive
If both persons have precognition, you'll not have a perfect fight. Both of them have strengths and weaknesses that can be used to win. Say one is stronger than the other. You can use ut to quickly tire the other out, using your strength to overwhelm your opponent. Maybe you are quicker, or have more reach. Even if the first so many moves do not kill, at one point someone moves in a direction that sets them up for winning or losing the fight. You do not yet see that a stone near you is something they can inevitably push you on, making you lose balance when this suddenly turns up. And then nowhere out but defeat.
We can take this further. Each instance of movement is a new precognition, so it costs time. You only see and understand the next move in a new instance. Based on that you make a new decision. So between a precognition and a decision is time.
People commit to actions in that time. If you're already swinging your axe you have very little other options to do. That means a commitment narrows down the options for that person, which can be taken advantage of. Or if they commit at the right time, nothing the other can do can result in an evasion or deflection. Maybe it just pushes someone off balance, which can be exploited again.
But finally, you still work with humans. Humans can make stupid decisions. Yes they see some outcomes ahead of time, but how can you tell if this will be good for you? Maybe you get blinded by an opportunity, moving in and unbalancing your opponent, realising too late you'll get your back against a wall and they will tear your heart out shortly after.
Perfect battles do not exist with physical and mental limitations and advantages.

If we assume that the precognition is perfect, both fighters will know exactly what's going to happen in the window of the precognition, including their own moves. So assuming the fighters have exactly the same window, the actual fight, where and when the decisions are made, would be happening a few seconds into the future. So the fight would be essentially the same as a regular fight.
If the precognitive window is different for the two fighters, the one with the longer window would not likely ever lose, because effectively they have precognition and their opponent doesn't. A skilled fighter can predict or guess their opponents moves without precognition and thus might be able to compensate for a small difference up to maybe 0.1s to 0.5s, especially if the other one is much less skilled.
A fighter might know that they are about to lose. Since a person would react to the knowledge that they are going to be hit for certain in a few seconds, the fighter would foresee that they are going to be reacting to the hit, before they actually foresee the hit itself. A really good fighter should be able to tell how the fight is going to end before it starts by seeing how they themselves will react in the near future to reactions to reactions to reactions, etc. to events in the future. Maybe this is a skill that takes years to master?
With less than perfect precognition, where the fighter sees possible futures, it's not much different from real fights, where fighters constantly try to predict their opponents moves. A big difference is that a few seconds is a long time in a melee fight so there might be a considerable cognitive load on a fighter trying to figure out what to do. Maybe the fighters would focus on only the near 0.5s or so, unless they foresee highly likely win or loss.

Yeah, I was thinking this may end up just being a "regular fight". It all depends on how good the precognition is.  I could see two people just standing there, waiting for the other's opening move, it slowly dawning on the both of them that both are precogs.

Agree with others re: you get to pick, but! we do (sort of) have a way for you to figure this out experimentally. (It wouldn't surprise me if someone has actually run this experiment in real life, I just don't have time to search right now. If anyone finds an existing real experiment please edit it in here.)
Create a game. Add lag so that choices are visible immediately but only take effect in game play after some duration. When there's no lag the game represents the current state of real life. When the lag only happens to one person, that represents the other person having precognition. When the lag happens to both people that represents both people having precognition. You can run this as, perhaps, a table top game with choices written down or represented by cards, or you can run it as a thought experiment in your head, and see how different parameters (how far in advance can you see, how can "future" choices be changed?) change the gameplay. (Perhaps precognition is fuzzy, you have to play as similar card as to what you indicated your plan was but not the exact same card...or one person is better at being un-precognible than the other so they have a wider range of choices...etc.)

Hand to hand
The time window of precognition is going to have a huge effect on how hand-to-hand works. With precognition times of more than a couple of seconds, one of the fighters will seek to run away, knowing that they can't win. The vast majority of real-world fights are over in a couple of strikes.
With a window of a tenth of a second, the two fighters would circle each other, with every feint and shuffle being broadcast through time. They wouldn't bother doing them unless they could connect. It would be a fight of attention span, waiting for the opponent to get distracted so you could come in with an effective attack.
If you ever watch MMA, you know how difficult it is to keep a fight from devolving into mat work (wrestling, or Brazilian Jiu jitsu). It's the inevitable state for well matched fighters. Precognition would make this inevitability more obvious.
What you would see is a significant increase in the value of strength, endurance, and speed. Being able to predict your opponent's moves and fighting styles, knowing how their reactions will get them to tangle their feet, knowing that your opponent will put up their guard when you do this, leaving that unprotected, is what almost all skill in martial arts revolves around. As such, the focus would shift to improving the raw physicality.
To an outside observer, equally matched combatants would approach each other with their hands poised to shoot out and grab. They'd slowly circle each other, then one would rush in, and it would be a wrestling match.
Blades
Bladed combat wouldn't be much different than hand-to-hand. Both opponents would see a probability cloud of where their opponent could get their blade to go, based on the blade's mass and the wielder's strength and speed. Again, if you have more than a couple of seconds, an inferior swordsman would just run, or fight defensively if they can't run.
One thing you'd see is increased use of tassels, cords, and scarves, used to distract, bind your opponent's weapon, or block their view. Two-handed techniques would be more popular because they increase the number of probabilities that someone has to keep track of. I suspect that shuriken and throwing knives might play a role in reducing your opponent's options.
Nonetheless, it wouldn't be very interesting to watch.
